# WSO2-AM: Publish a webservice takes long time ( > 3 minutes)

Tags: wso2

Publishing a webservice on WSO2 API Manager, takes a long time. It takes more than 3 minutes.

Increasing the loglevel to debug, shows in the "wso2carbon.log" file, a transaction that takes very long. Is there an explanation for?

*NOTE: We run out-of-the-box WSO2 API Manager, only changed the master-datasources.xml to an Oracle database with a wso2carbon user.*

TID: [0] [AM] [2013-12-17 15:33:27,778] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.statistics.StatisticsLog} -  Total Number of Active Transactions      : 1
Transaction 1 (Active For 192899ms) :
        org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCTransactionManager.beginTransaction(JDBCTransactionManager.java:100)
        org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.beginTransaction(EmbeddedRegistry.java:443)
        org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.beginTransaction(CacheBackedRegistry.java:439)
        org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.beginTransaction(UserRegistry.java:433)
        org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:1154)
        org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:371)
        org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:45)
        org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_addAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:446)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue in our environment. Should be a combination of OS (Suse 64 bit), Java 7 64 bit, WSO2 AM and VMWare.

In version AM 1.6 creating a service takes now a few seconds.